# 404 redirect error with Auth0 in a PhoneGap Cordova Vanilla JS App

Tags: javascript, cordova, auth0, phonegap

After following this guide https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/phonegap to setup Auth0 with the PhoneGap configuration for my Vanilla JS based app, I am able load the lock screen for Auth0, login, but then it redirects back to my original index page and then loads the lock screen again.

The only console error I get is this:

```
GET https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/a5d8f0e1f22ad3742dc6f3f9dbab4a01?d=404&s=160 404 ()
```

I am not sure how to debug with this error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Drew - Hi, where did you get your phonegap quickstart sample from? Visited the link you referenced above but Download / Fork on github links were broken. Just curious whether they were working for you very recently or whether you are referring to an older sample? Happy to assist if I can get hold of the official quickstart you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-javascript-samples/tree/master/01-Login